# Custom form module

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a custom form named `user_form_expiry`, how can I access that form from the admin panel similar to other Drupal's built in forms like `user_register_form`?

Comment: how did you create it? give us more Details.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a menu hook in your module and give the form name as your callback arg. Something like this:

`<?php
function MYMODULE_menu(){
  $items['admin/my-path'] = array(
    'title' => 'User expiry',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_form_expiry'),
    'access arguments' => 'access content', // you probably want something more restrictive here
    'menu_name' => 'management',
    //'weight' => 1,
  );
}
function user_form_expiry($form, &$form_state){
// form API code here
}`

That said, I suspect that your use case would work better using hook_form_alter(). What are you trying to achieve here?